# How to recover files on dead WD 1TB External Hard Drive?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I accept defeat. This piece of crap is dead. Is there anyway to recover the files on it? Stupid me for never backing up on cloud, DVD's, etc.

Please I need those files. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues and recovered a large part of a damaged hard drive using [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Basically, this involves (assuming repairing a windows formatted partition):

1. Boot into Linux, and clone the damaged partition or the entire disk into a big file on another healthy hard drive. e.g.

   dd if=/dev/sda6 bs=1k conv=sync,noerror | gzip -c | dd of=machine_sda6_img.gz bs=1k
2. use testdisk to recreate the partition (only if partition cannot be found, otherwise skip this step).

   gunzip machine_sda6_img.gz
   testdisk machine_sda6_img

   *you may need to give the partition type and some partition parameters if that information is damaged.
3. On Windows (XP or other versions) or a virtual machine in VirtualBox, mount the partially repaired image and fix w/ CHKDSK.
   download and install OSFmount:

   wget http://www.osforensics.com/downloads/osfmount.exe (32-bit) or

   wget http://www.osforensics.com/downloads/osfmount_x64.exe (64-bit)

   mount machine_sda6_img (do not use "read only" mode), e.g. as drive E:
   run `cmd` and type:

   chkdsk /f e:

This made the partition visible to me again, and I was able to copy the majority of the files out to a second hard drive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But my PC freezes every time I connect the External to PC. How else could I do it?

Comment: Was this on Linux? Try connect your hd to a linux machine and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Hirens Boot](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) in order to solve this.

Here's the step to in USB: [Hiren's BootCD From USB Flash Drive (USB Pen Drive)](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk).

Or you can use this Tool [Hiren's CD 2 Bootable USB Installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hirenscd2bootableusb/)

Comment: I tried that before, but my whenever I connect my External to PC, it freezes.

Comment: I think it wont freeze, its just a DOS program, theres a lot of HDD Recovery Tools to choose from.

Comment: Open the WD enclosure and see if the hard drive inside has a standard sata and power connector, if it does, remove the drive and connect it to your PC using a generic sata to usb adapter, does it work now?